# .htaccess passes through everything

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble with my .htaccess file and don't really know why. It works on localhost but passes through every url when published on the server. The server is a Linux environment with apache 2.2. This is my .htaccess (The line 6 specifically):

```
RewriteEngine   On
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace2
RewriteBase     /var/www/html/resurs/
RewriteRule     ^ajaxLogin$                     /core/login/ajaxLogin.php
RewriteRule     ^handleForm$                    /core/form/handler.php
RewriteRule     ^login/$                        /core/login/login.php [L]
RewriteRule             ^logout/$                                               /index.php?logout [L]
RewriteRule     ^shell/uploadedFiles/([a-f0-9()]+)\.(\w)$ - [S=7]
RewriteRule     ^core/login/ajaxLogin\.php|core/form/handler\.php|core/login/login\.php|index\.php\?logout$ - [S=6]
RewriteRule     ^shell/(images|css|javascript)/((\w+)\.(\w+))$   - [S=5]
RewriteRule     ^core/(images|css|javascript)/((\w+)\.(\w+))$   - [S=4]
RewriteRule     ^core/admin/(images|css|javascript)/((\w+)\.(\w+))$   - [S=3]
RewriteRule     ^mods/(\w+)/(images|css|javascript)/((\w+)\.(\w+))$   - [S=2]
RewriteRule     ^index\.php - [S=1]
RewriteRule     ^(?!index\.php\?path)(.+(/.+)*/{0,1})$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,B,NS]
```

When accessing my.site/login/ the Rewrite logs say:

```
X.X.X.X - - [15/Aug/2014:10:48:01 +0200] [my.site/sid#2b770f4adef0][rid#2b7713535100/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /login/
X.X.X.X - - [15/Aug/2014:10:48:01 +0200] [my.site/sid#2b770f4adef0][rid#2b7713535100/initial] (1) pass through /login/
```

It feels like it doesn't even enters my .htaccess

Comment: *"It feels like it doesn't even enters my .htaccess"* -- It's easy to test that: Enter garbage into your .htaccess and reload the page. If you get an internal server error, that is not the problem ;-)

Comment: @Sumurai8 It's confirmed, it doesn't enter the file

Answer (score 0):

As you say that it doesn't read the .htaccess file at all, make sure that the following directives are set correctly:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

If this is defined, it should be in the server config (httpd.conf) or in a virtual host block inside that config file. This is the file Apache will be looking for. It should be .htaccess by default though, but if you change this to, for example, `.unicorn`, it will check for `.unicorn` in every directory instead. See [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#accessfilename).

Also make sure that .htaccess is allowed to override anything. If it isn't allowed to override anything, it will not even check what is in the file. `AllowOverride` must be set to at least `FileInfo`. The directive must be in the server config in a `<directory>` block:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

Again, see [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for more information.